# Laravel Repeating Task

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I need a task:

- which can be turned on or off (only for admins/authorized users)
- which runs in a constant loop
- which should display a timer to every user each loop, 60 seconds for example (with pusher)
- if the user connects to this task 20 seconds in, it should continue from the remaining 40 seconds

How would I achieve something like that? I was thinking about a combination of events, queues and tasks, but I'm not sure how I should use them to create my task.

Comment: What is the scope of the task? Is is one task controlled by many users? Or a single task for a given user?

Comment: @Spholt Its one task controlled by many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can use the scheduler to control the frequency of your task

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

You can then use a truth constraint to check whether it should run or not like so:

```
$schedule->command('your:task')->when(function () {
    // Do a config check / DB check / Cache check here
    return true;
});
```

I would suggest setting a value in something like the caching layer rather than accessing a file or using a relational database. This is a task which will be run every second so you don't want anything which could be too resource intensive!

You can then have a command to set the value in the cache that you are checking. This command should only be run by those users you give permission.

Comment: Thanks, sadly it has to run constantly. My solution was to use Queues/Jobs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) . When the job is done, I dispatch the same job at the end of the handle() method and it queues itself afterwards. I use cron jobs to watch my queues.